# mongo query fetching embedded document

Tags: mongodb

based on this :

```
db.room.save({name:'public',msg:[{to:'Jo',msg:'whats up'},{to:'Jo',msg:'dude?'}]})
db.room.find()
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f86282a87850ac4bfe9a664"), "name" : "public", "msg" : [ { "to" : "Jo", "msg" : "whats up" }, { "to" : "Jo", "msg" : "dude?" } ] }
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
db.room.find(????)
> {"name" : "public", "to" : "Jo", "msg" : "whats up"}
> {"name" : "public", "to" : "Jo", "msg" : "dude?"}
```

What query should i use in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it is not possible to retrieve individual embedded documents.  Only top-level documents are returned.

There is a feature request for this functionality.  "Support for positional ($) operator in fields to return specifier" - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828

This feature request is slated for version 2.1.1, but this is subject to change.

A similar question was asked on Google Groups a while back, "Retrieving DBObject from an array of DBObjects" - http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/7d2c8919dd6c4dd8 the question is on the Java Driver specifically, but the answer is still applicable.

If you want to modify embedded documents, you can do so as described in the Google Groups response.  Additionally, the new Aggregation Framework contains an $unwind method, which you might want to experiment with.  If you would like to print out only the embedded documents, you will have to do it via your application, or consider changing your document structure such that the documents that you want to display are top-level.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this clearly help a lot. At least i won't go browsing the internet for hours just to find that it is (almost) impossible at the moment. Thank you a lot